# Where to place <form> tags correctly?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know where to place the  tags correctly and if my code is missing something maybe. When I place the form tags in my code, everything moves as you guys can see in the code snippet.

I would like it to be as shown in the picture below.

This may seem like a very basic question but, to be honest, I don't understand why this happens.

This is what my page looks like without the  tags:

[image: 1]

Any guidance will be highly appreciated, thanks beforehand.

```css
#main-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* --------------------- add bar container ----------------- */
#add-bar-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    background-color: white;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#profile-picture{
    height: 30px;
    width: 35px;
}

#search-button{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray; 

    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#search-bar{
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
}

#user-info-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;

    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#panels-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#left-panel{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
}

#center-panel{
    background-color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 3;
}

#right-panel{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">

    <title>Stripe - Agent</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main-container">
  <form action="" id="search-form">
    <div id="add-bar-container">
        <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="q">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <img src="../icons/profile_img.png" alt="Avatar" id="profile-picture">
    </div>
</form>
    <div id="user-info-bar">
    
    </div>
    <div id="panels-container">
      <div id="left-panel">
      
      </div>
      <div id="center-panel">

      </div>
      <div id="right-panel">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="add-bar-container">
<form action="" id="search-form">
        <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="q">
        <button id="search-button" type="submit" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        <img src="../icons/profile_img.png" alt="Avatar" id="profile-picture">
   </form>
</div
```

the form should be inside the div

Answer (score 0):

**First**, if you want to state that a document is written in English, then it is enough to use `<html lang="en">`, so lose the nonsense `<meta lang="en">`.

**Second**, about the style, you need to have a MEDIA attribute on your LINK loading CSS files so you aren't sending screen-specific information to all targets! Add media attribute, surly that style is not for any UA, you can [read this article about it](https://cutcodedown.com/article/whats_wrong_with_YOUR_website_part4). Also, you better have a logical directory structure, so you don't have to "up-tree" link, just "down-tree", in other words, structure your page the same way it’s called by the browser!

For example, the three directory pathing methods:

up-tree: …/styles/styles.css – /FAIL/

rooted: /styles/styles.css – /FAIL/

down-tree: styles/styles.css – /WIN/

**Third**, stop polluting your markup with class and id while you don't need them. If you have just one form, you can just select that by `form {}` in your CSS, or for button inside form, `button {}/form button {}` is enough.

**Fourth**, don't use `<div>` inside `<form>`, use `<feildset>`, It also groups multiple form elements into related sections, [read more on this and about how to make forms](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/stop-making-incomplete-inaccessible-forms-6b8e38a690ff) and [this page from MDN about fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). Also, use `<label>`, placeholder is not a label!

So, May I suggest this markup and style as a refactor:

```
header {
    height: 6em;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

header div {
  flex-basis:50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  display:flex;
  background-color:#fff;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

header div img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 35px;
}

header div form {
  display:flex;
}

header div form fieldset {
  border:none;
}

header div form input {
    width: 12em;
    border: none;
}

header div form button{
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray; 
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

header #userInfoBar {
  background-color:#ececec;
}


main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

#left-panel{
    flex-basis:20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#center-panel{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 3;
}

#right-panel{
    flex-basis:20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
    <title>Stripe - Agent</title>
</head><body>
  
  <header>
    <div>
      <form action="action.php">
        <fieldset>
          <label>
            Search:
            <input 
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="What are you looking for?" 
                   name="searchBar" 
                   required>
          </label>
        </fieldset>
        <button value="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>    
      </form>
      <img src="../icons/profile_img.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div id="userInfoBar">

    </div>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <div id="left-panel">
  
    </div>
    <div id="center-panel">

    </div>
    <div id="right-panel">

    </div>
  </main>
  
</body>
</html>
```